# Can I edit a file loaded by jquery on the fly?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

Can I edit an html file loaded by jquery on the fly? I want to load the html file and then manipulate it using jquery to copy some content into it.

All the examples that i see point to loading the file and then copying the content to a div.

```
$("div").load('loadfile.html');
```

regards

Comment: Are you thinking of creating a template in HTML and then loading the template with data and appending it to your page?

Comment: You can get the file with `$.get()`.

Comment: yes, it involves creating an Html Template and then copying data from various sources using Jquery and then appending it to various parts of the template.

Comment: just use `$("<div />")` so it's not on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load it into a newly created div that isn't currently on the page

```
 var inMemoryDiv = $("<div />").load('loadfile.html')
                               .find('#someElement')
                               .html("new content");
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how much data you need to insert into your table, you may want to consider [`jTemplates`](http://jtemplates.tpython.com/).

jTemplates allows you to create an HTML template and then creates the filled out HTML when you pass it a data object or array.

Dave Ward has an example [on his blog](http://encosia.com/use-jquery-and-aspnet-ajax-to-build-a-client-side-repeater/).

His template:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Excerpt</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {#foreach $T.d as post}
    <tr>
      <td>{$T.post.Date}</td>
      <td><a href="{$T.post.Link}">{$T.post.Title}</a></td>
      <td>{$T.post.Description}</td>
    </tr>
    {#/for}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Loading the template with data:

```
function ApplyTemplate(msg) {
  // This method loads the HTML template and
  //  prepares the container div to accept data.
  $('#Container').setTemplateURL('RSSTable.htm');

  // This method applies the JSON array to the 
  //  container's template and renders it.
  $('#Container').processTemplate(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$("div").load('loadfile.html').find('#someDivId').html("new text");
```

Comment: yes, but doesn't that still involve copying the html content into a div on the page before editing it?

Answer (score 0):

.load() is a shortcut to another jquery function. Instead of using it you could try using this:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'loadfile.html', type: 'POST', data: { 'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2' }).done(function(data) {
// Everything in this block is executed as soon as the ajax request is done. The var 'data' will return all the info you requested, same as .load(), but now you can be sure that the DOM will be updated when you process your changes.  
    $('div').html(data);
    ....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far I as I understand your question,

Assume that div#result is hidden. By the below load method it allows you to load a specific part of the loadfile.html file. I assume that #container is the div#container you want to load from loadfile.html(rather than loading the whole file).

```
$('div#result').load('loadfile.html #container');
```

Do whatever the manipulation you want to do. Copy the edited content to whatever the div you want.

```
$('div#result').empty(); Or .remove()
```

to remove the div#result from DOM.

If you have any questions please be kind enough to raise it. Thanks

Comment: that's how i would do it, but i was looking for alternative ways of an alternative way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this. This will only work if file is located locally.

```
 $(function () {
        var result = "";
        var file = "Default.aspx";

        //Assuming local file. 
        $.get(file, handleData);

        //If remote file, use $.ajax

        //handle data that is returned
        function handleData(data) {
            data = data.replace(/\/\/\<\!\[CDATA\[/ig, "/*");
            data = data.replace(/\/\/\]\]>/ig, "*/");
            result = data.replace("html", "test");

            alert(result);
        }

    });
```